# Problema com currentTime JS

Tags: javascript

Olá estou com um problema no currentTime, pelo que eu li ele recebe apenas valores numericos, porém existem campos no meu codigo que servem para o usuario digitar um valor que ele queira em segundos, e clicar em enviar, ao clicar, um Span, printa o valor inserido acima, e eu queria que o valor fosse puxado pelo currentTime que no momento esta com um valor fixo, existe alguma forma de contornar esse problema?

A duvida real é como posso contornar isso, para que o id=result seja inserido dentro do current exemplo vid.currentTime: ('result'); (sei que esse exemplo nao é possivel, só estou demonstrando).

Desde já obriado.

```
<html> 
  
    
<body> 

  


 <!--  Setar Tempo  -->

  <div class="container">
      <form  action="#">
          <label for="tmpInic">Tempo inicial:</label>
          <input type="text" id="tmpInic" name="tmpInic">

          <input type="button" value="Enviar" onClick="pr()"><br><br>
          Tempo Inicial ajustado: <span id="result"></span><br><br>
        
        </form>
  </div>

      <!-- Botao para pular intervalo  -->
<div class="container">

<button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">Pular Intervalo</button><br> 

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 
</video>
</div>





<script>
/* guardar informa valores */
function pr() {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById('tmpInic').value;
    }

    
/* pular intervalo */
document.getElementById("mntInput").addEventListener("input", e => {
  let mnt = e.target.value;
  document.getElementById("sgdOutput").innerHTML = mnt * 60;
});


var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function getCurTime() { 
  alert(vid.currentTime);
} 

function setCurTime() { 
  vid.currentTime= 304;
} 
</script> 


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

Altere a função conforme abaixo:

```
function setCurTime() { 
  vid.currentTime= document.getElementById("result2").textContent;
}
```

Aí coloque por exemplo:

- Tempo Intervalo: 5
- Clique em Enviar
- O vídeo será posicionado em 5s

Obs.: o currentTime é em segundos, ou seja, se você quiser usar o formato MM:SS (exemplo: 04:40), será necessário converter esse tempo em segundos.

Comment: Ahh caramba vou testar, eu tentei algo parecido mas nao assim, sim o tempo é em segundos obrigado mesmo vou testar aqui.

Comment: Ah mano... eu vou dar um BEIJO em voce veio... pqp, me salvou o dia cara caramba eu estava a exatos 4 dias tentando isso